# Not able to run test cases in nightwatch framework on ec2 amazon linux instance through jenkins

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

While running the testcases through jenkins on ec2 instance,I am getting error message.

Here's my nightwatch configuration:

```
{
    "src_folders" : ["test"],
    "globals_path": "globals.js",
    "output_folder" : "reports",
    "custom_commands_path" : "./commands",
    "custom_assertions_path" : "./assertions",
    "page_objects_path":"./pages",
    "test_workers" : {
        "enabled" : false, 
        "workers" : "auto"
      },


"selenium" : {
  "start_process" : true,
  "server_path" : "./bin/selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0.jar",
  "log_path" : "",
  "port" : 4444,
  "cli_args" : {
    "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "./bin/chromedriver_linux"
  }
},

"test_settings" : {
  "default" : {
    "request_timeout_options": {
      "timeout": 100000
    },
    "videos": {
      "enabled": false,          
      "delete_on_pass": false,   
      "path": "reports/videos",
      "format": "mp4",
      "resolution": "1280x720",
      "fps": 15,
      "display": ":",
      "pixel_format": "yuv420p",
      "inputFormat": "mjpeg"
    },
    "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
    "selenium_port"  : 4444,
    "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
    "screenshots" : { 
      "enabled" : false, 
      "on_failure" : true, 
      "on_error" : true, 
      "path" : "./screenshots" 
    },
    "end_session_on_fail" : true,
    "skip_testcases_on_fail" : false,
    "use_xpath" : true,
    "globals" : {
      "url" : "http://ec30-3-100-2-16.us-north-10.compute.amazonws.com:1000/login"
    }, 
    "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "chromeOptions": {
        "w3c": false,
        "args" : ["headless","no-sandbox"]
      },
      "javascriptEnabled": true,
      "acceptSslCerts": true
    }
  }
}
```

}

getting below error message in the console :

```
Login Test Test Suite
==========================
- Connecting to localhost on port 4444...

Connected to localhost on port 4444 (31794ms).
  Using: chrome (81.0.4044.129) on Linux platform.

Running:  Verify user is able to login  

    POST  /wd/hub/session/2a3ca3b508f6dda4d0933225c41824a4/url - ECONNRESET
Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:604:14)
    at Socket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:400:25)
 Error while running .navigateTo() protocol action: An unknown error has occurred.

    POST  /wd/hub/session/2a3ca3b508f6dda4d0933225c41824a4/elements - ECONNRESET
Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:604:14)
    at Socket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:400:25)
 Error while running .locateMultipleElements() protocol action: An unknown error has occurred.
```

I have installed the chrome browser(81.0.4044.129) in ec2 instance and their respective chrome linux driver

**selenium server** : selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0.jar

**Note:**
I configured the Jenkins in my local machine(MAC OS) and its working fine.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: do you know if your application is accessible on ec2? you are trying to load localhost?

Comment: @Raju I am not trying to open the localhost, in my script I am passing the browser.globals.url(i.e http://ec30-3-100-2-16.us-north-10.compute.amazonws.com:1000/login ) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you security group attached to the EC2 server doesn't have ICMP IPV4 inbound rules accessible to your server running this nightwatch script. Try adding your nightwatch server IP address in the ICMP IPV4 inbound rules of the ec2 server you provided in the URL or you can even make it publicly accessible. I hope this resolves your issue.